# É possível realizar um innerJoin para saber a quantidade da segunda tabela?

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo uma base de dados com duas entidades, onde a entidade "A" é uma categoria, e em cada categoria contem vários itens, no caso entidade "B", o que eu preciso saber é: é possível trazer as informações da entidade A com a quantidade de itens da tabela B?

```
SELECT tabelaA.*, tabelaB.count(*) FROM tabelaA INNER JOIN tabelaB 
WHERE tabelaA.id = tabelaB.id
GROUP BY tabelaA.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem mas acho que é isto. use alias para o nome das tabela fica mais limpo.

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.categoria) as ContarCategoria FROM tabelaA A INNER JOIN tabela B  ON A.id = B.id GROUP BY A.id;
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, mas eu tive um outro problema, mas isso não é urgente responder, quando a tabela B não tem nenhuma `row` ele não retorna valor nenhum.